# Radio Button não não funciona

Tags: javascript, html

Criei um formulário e coloquei um radio button desabilitado e deixei ele ser habilitado no click de um botão, quando o botão é apertado ele fica habilitado porém não consigo trocar a opção, o radio fica travado em uma opção

script para habilitar o radio button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#EditarDados").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#nome").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#sobrenome").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#email").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#sexo").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#sexo2").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#telefone").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#celular").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#senha").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#categoriaPerfil").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#observa").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#formacao").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#senha").prop("disabled", false);
  }); 

});
```

HTML

```
<p>          
  <input required name="Cd_sexo" id="sexo" value="Masculino" type="radio" id="rd_masculino" <?php echo $Result_sexoM ?> disabled="disabled"/>
  <label for="rd_masculino">Masculino</label>
  <input required name="Cd_sexo" id="sexo2" type="radio" value="Feminino" id="rd_feminino" <?php echo $Result_sexoF ?> disabled="disabled"/>
  <label for="rd_feminino">Feminino</label>
</p>
```

Button

```
<button class="btn blue center-align"  name="Editar" id="EditarDados">Editar Dados
</button>
```

php

```
<?php
           include_once("../ibico/php/usuario_class.php");
          $result =usuario::PopulaPerfil();



            $Result_sexoM = '';
                  $Result_sexoF = '';
            $result_select= utf8_encode($result['nm_area_atuacao']);

           if($result['sx_sexo']=="Masculino")
           {
            $Result_sexoM ="checked";
           }
           else
           {
            $Result_sexoF ="checked";
           }

           ?>
```

Comment: Cade o btn "EditarDados" ?

Comment: Cara não conheço muito de php, mas se vc tirar a tag php funciona normalmente.

Comment: A tag estou usando para pegar do banco o sexo que foi definido, e pois habilito a edição no click do botão para alterar o sexo, todo o formulário de alteração fiz assim, só o radio button que desabilita e não vai

Comment: O que está retornando o `$Result_sexoM` e `$Result_sexoF`?

Comment: Retorna o sexo do usuário

Comment: Isso deu pra entender, o problema é que sem o `PHP` o `script` está funcionando, logo o problema deve estar no conteúdo dessas variáveis.

Comment: Não vi q suas 2 variáveis foram inicializadas, então minha resposta é invalida, com os códigos na mesma página não consegui reproduzir o erro.

Comment: tranquilo vlw pela tentativa